# Replace missing values from another column - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm fairly new to python and was wondering whether it is possible to loop through a bunch of columns and replace missing values with another column that has the same name but with a suffix.

For example:

---obs---|---col1---|---col2---|---col1_suffix---|---col2_suffix---|

----1-----|---NaN---|----50-----|------20----------| -----60------------

----2-----|---200---|----NaN----|------30---------| ------100---------

Will want to loop through from col1 to up  to colN and replace the NaN with the value in col1_suffix up to colN_suffix. So in above example, col1 NaN will be replaced with a value of 20 and col2 NaN will be replaced with 100.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using `panda`, you could do this:

```
for col in ['col1', 'col2']:
    df[col] = df[col].fillna(df[col+'_suffix'])
```

A more generic version:

```
for col in df.columns:
    if col+'_suffix' in df.columns:
        df[col] = df[col].fillna(df[col+'_suffix'])
```